# Laravel/NodeJS - npm ERR! Missing script: "watch"

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

I've upgraded to Laravel 9 recently.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "axios": "^0.21",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
    "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
    "vite": "^3.0.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "alpinejs": "^3.8.1",
    "laravel-echo": "^1.11.3",
    "pusher-js": "^7.0.3"
  },
  "name": "beastburst-website",
  "description": "<p align=\"center\"><a href=\"https://laravel.com\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/art/master/logo-lockup/5%20SVG/2%20CMYK/1%20Full%20Color/laravel-logolockup-cmyk-red.svg\" width=\"400\"></a></p>",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "tailwind.config.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://code.scarsgaming.net/BeastBurst/BeastBurst-Website.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

When I run `npm run watch` I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "watch"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/venelin/.npm/_logs/2022-08-31T11_40_11_910Z-debug-0.log
```

Any idea why and how can I fix that?

Comment: Well, there is no `watch` script specified under `scripts: { ... }` in your package.json

Comment: What are you trying to do? `watch` is not part of your scripts 
`
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
  }
`

Answer (score 0):

The default bundler for Laravel now is Vite as you can clearly see from your package.json

If you do not want to use Vite, use this [guide](https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/UPGRADE.md#migrating-from-vite-to-laravel-mix) to switch to mix

I should also mention that [Vite](https://vitejs.dev) is much faster that mix.

Answer (score 0):

try `npm run dev` it will work like `npm run watch` that is because Laravel 9 now uses Vite.